# How to call method every 30 second?

Tags: android, timer

I am a new develop of Android. I want to create an Application about time. The question is "how to call method every 30 second?" 
Example: Every 30 second the application will send some message.

I do not know how to do it firstly, I use this function

```
time = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(isDistanceStable()){
                    Toast.makeText(ChangeStatus.this, "Your speed is normal.", 3).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ChangeStatus.this, "Your speed is abnormal.", 3).show();
                    callManualRed();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                time.cancel();
                //intervalCheckDistance();
            }

        }.start();

    }
```

but how to call it every 30 second. Please give me an example or some solutions to solve it. Thank you very much and Sorry with my English

Comment: You need to run this even if your application is closed or in background?

Answer (score 2):

```
cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 30000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // Method
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        cdt.start(); // Call Again After 30 seconds
    }
}.start();
```

Remember to call `cdt.cancel();` when you want to end the timer